# Issue with Recipient Merge Field

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert, merge-field, lightning-email-template

AS per Salesforce's documentation [Email Alert Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_wfalerts.htm&type=5)

```
Lightning Email Templates

In Lightning email templates, merge fields are resolved for activity-enabled objects 
only, except Contact and Lead merge fields.
```

I have used an email alert (OBJECT: Contact) in my Flow (Triggering object Contact) , Lightning Email  Template (Related Entity Type: Contact)

In the email template I have used the Merge field {{{Recipient.FirstName}}} which as per the documentation is correct.

Yet, my flow thrown an error

```
core.email.template.TemplateRenderingException: We don't recognize the field prefix 
Recipient
```

Is using classic email template the only option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Recipient merge fields cannot be used in Flow Email Alert Actions currently. There is an idea that promotes this as an enhancement: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVTyUAN/set-email-alert-recipients-from-process-builder-or-workflow

As a workaround you can try to rebuild the Email template as a text template variable in the flow and trigger it with a simple Email Action.

Comment: That's what i ended up doing - simple Email Action